# Is it possible to create partitions on db tables with django==1.11 and postgresql?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, partitioning

Is it possible to create partitions on db tables with django==1.11 and postgresql? Thanks a lot!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can. But you have to do it manually (ie, sql in a migration) as I don't think there is inbuilt django support for it.

Comment: Thanks, I will be building the partitions manually. thanks

Comment: Hello everyone! after to research about this point, I can apply partitions on my tables using the architect package ( you can see in: http://architect.readthedocs.io/features/partition/ ), I recommended this, it is very very easy to use, thanks a lot!